# sunshine app is giving filenotfoundexception when i click the refresh button

Tags: android, json

particularly, very new in android, and dont know well to debug it. the issue is whenever i click refresh button nothing happens, instead it had to show the realdata, it keeps on displaying the fake data. logcat says that file does not exist, could not  find errors here.
here is my code

**main activity**

```
package com.example.android.sunshine.app;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     /**  if (savedInstanceState == null){
         getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
         .add(R.id.container, new ForecastFragment())
         .commit();

         }*/
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        if (id == R.id.action_refresh){
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**forecastFragment**

```
package com.example.android.sunshine.app;

import android.net.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.support.v4.app.*;
import android.text.format.*;
import android.util.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;

import org.json.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;


/**
 * Created by Nabahat on 7/8/2015.
 */
public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment {

    private ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter;
    public ForecastFragment(){}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater){
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.forecastfragment, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id==R.id.action_refresh){
            FetchWeatherTask weatherTask = new FetchWeatherTask();
            weatherTask.execute("94043");
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        String[] forecastArray = {
                "Today - Sunny - 88/63",
                "Tomorrow - Foggy - 70/40",
                "Weds - Cloudy - 72/63",
                "Thurs - Asteroids - 75/65",
                "Fri - Heavy Rain - 65/56",
                "Sat - HELP TRAPPED IN WEATHERSTATION - 60/51",
                "Sun - Sunny - 80/68"
        };

        List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>(
                Arrays.asList(forecastArray));

        ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActivity(),
                R.layout.list_item_forecast,
                R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,
                weekForecast);
        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
        listView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }

    public class FetchWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> {

        private final String LOG_TAG = FetchWeatherTask.class.getSimpleName();

        /* The date/time conversion code is going to be moved outside the asynctask later,
  * so for convenience we're breaking it out into its own method now.
  */
        private String getReadableDateString(long time){
            // Because the API returns a unix timestamp (measured in seconds),
            // it must be converted to milliseconds in order to be converted to valid date.
            SimpleDateFormat shortenedDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd");
            return shortenedDateFormat.format(time);
        }

        /**
         * Prepare the weather high/lows for presentation.
         */
        private String formatHighLows(double high, double low) {
            // For presentation, assume the user doesn't care about tenths of a degree.
            long roundedHigh = Math.round(high);
            long roundedLow = Math.round(low);

            String highLowStr = roundedHigh + "/" + roundedLow;
            return highLowStr;
        }

        /**
         * Take the String representing the complete forecast in JSON Format and
         * pull out the data we need to construct the Strings needed for the wireframes.
         *
         * Fortunately parsing is easy:  constructor takes the JSON string and converts it
         * into an Object hierarchy for us.
         */
        private String[] getWeatherDataFromJson(String forecastJsonStr, int numDays)
                throws JSONException {

            // These are the names of the JSON objects that need to be extracted.
            final String OWM_LIST = "list";
            final String OWM_WEATHER = "weather";
            final String OWM_TEMPERATURE = "temp";
            final String OWM_MAX = "max";
            final String OWM_MIN = "min";
            final String OWM_DESCRIPTION = "main";

            JSONObject forecastJson = new JSONObject(forecastJsonStr);
            JSONArray weatherArray = forecastJson.getJSONArray(OWM_LIST);

            // OWM returns daily forecasts based upon the local time of the city that is being
            // asked for, which means that we need to know the GMT offset to translate this data
            // properly.

            // Since this data is also sent in-order and the first day is always the
            // current day, we're going to take advantage of that to get a nice
            // normalized UTC date for all of our weather.

            Time dayTime = new Time();
            dayTime.setToNow();

            // we start at the day returned by local time. Otherwise this is a mess.
            int julianStartDay = Time.getJulianDay(System.currentTimeMillis(), dayTime.gmtoff);

            // now we work exclusively in UTC
            dayTime = new Time();

            String[] resultStrs = new String[numDays];
            for(int i = 0; i < weatherArray.length(); i++) {
                // For now, using the format "Day, description, hi/low"
                String day;
                String description;
                String highAndLow;

                // Get the JSON object representing the day
                JSONObject dayForecast = weatherArray.getJSONObject(i);

                // The date/time is returned as a long.  We need to convert that
                // into something human-readable, since most people won't read "1400356800" as
                // "this saturday".
                long dateTime;
                // Cheating to convert this to UTC time, which is what we want anyhow
                dateTime = dayTime.setJulianDay(julianStartDay+i);
                day = getReadableDateString(dateTime);

                // description is in a child array called "weather", which is 1 element long.
                JSONObject weatherObject = dayForecast.getJSONArray(OWM_WEATHER).getJSONObject(0);
                description = weatherObject.getString(OWM_DESCRIPTION);

                // Temperatures are in a child object called "temp".  Try not to name variables
                // "temp" when working with temperature.  It confuses everybody.
                JSONObject temperatureObject = dayForecast.getJSONObject(OWM_TEMPERATURE);
                double high = temperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MAX);
                double low = temperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MIN);

                highAndLow = formatHighLows(high, low);
                resultStrs[i] = day + " - " + description + " - " + highAndLow;
            }
            for (String s : resultStrs){
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Forecast entry: " + s);
            }
            return resultStrs;
        }
        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(String... params){

            if(params.length == 0){
                return null;
            }

            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            String forecastJsonStr = null;

            String format = "jason";
            String units = "metric";
            int numDays = 7;

            try {

                final  String FORECAST_BASE_URL =
                        "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?";
                final String QUERY_PARAM = "q";
                final String FORMAT_PARAM = "mode";
                final String UNITS_PARAM = "units";
                final String DAYS_PARAM = "cnt";

                Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(FORECAST_BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                        .appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM, params[0])
                        .appendQueryParameter(FORMAT_PARAM, format)
                        .appendQueryParameter(UNITS_PARAM, units)
                        .appendQueryParameter(DAYS_PARAM, Integer.toString(numDays))
                        .build();

                URL url = new URL(builtUri.toString());

                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Built URI " + builtUri.toString());

                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("API_KEY", "c84aeef73dfe54e9ec696154cfb89a5a");
                urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                urlConnection.connect();

                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                if (inputStream == null) {
                    return null;
                }
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line + "\n");
                }

                if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                    return null;
                }
                forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Forecast JSON String: "+ forecastJsonStr);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error ", e);
                return null;

            } finally{
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
                if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (final IOException e) {
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error closing stream", e);
                    }
                }
            }
        try{
            return getWeatherDataFromJson(forecastJsonStr, numDays);
        } catch (JSONException e){
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String[] result){
            if (result != null){
                mForecastAdapter.clear();
                for (String dayForecastStr : result){
                    mForecastAdapter.add(dayForecastStr);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Logcat**

```
10670-10670/com.example.android.sunshine.app W/art﹕ Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.internal.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
07-09 06:12:19.182  10670-10692/com.example.android.sunshine.app W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-09 06:12:19.182  10670-10692/com.example.android.sunshine.app W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa5403460, error=EGL_SUCCESS
07-09 06:12:19.627  10670-10677/com.example.android.sunshine.app W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 21.107ms
07-09 06:12:21.091  10670-10764/com.example.android.sunshine.app V/FetchWeatherTask﹕ Built URI http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=94043&mode=jason&units=metric&cnt=7
07-09 06:12:21.163  10670-10670/com.example.android.sunshine.app W/InputEventReceiver﹕ Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
07-09 06:12:22.087  10670-10764/com.example.android.sunshine.app E/FetchWeatherTask﹕ Error
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=94043&mode=jason&units=metric&cnt=7
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:206)
            at com.example.android.sunshine.app.ForecastFragment$FetchWeatherTask.doInBackground(ForecastFragment.java:217)
            at com.example.android.sunshine.app.ForecastFragment$FetchWeatherTask.doInBackground(ForecastFragment.java:75)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
07-09 06:12:31.513  10670-10677/com.example.android.sunshine.app W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 8.898ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your log, same problem have been solved by checking the response, adding these two line code

```
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 ( compatible ) ");
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept","*/*");
```

and set

```
urlConnection.setDoOutput(false);
```

You can refer to these two answers:

[HttpURLConnection java.io.FileNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16255823/httpurlconnection-java-io-filenotfoundexception)

[FileNotFoundException while getting the InputStream object from HttpURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379247/filenotfoundexception-while-getting-the-inputstream-object-from-httpurlconnectio)

Comment: try remove urlConnection.setDoOutput(false);

Comment: do you need to add urlConnection.setRequestProperty("API_KEY", "c84aeef73dfe54e9ec696154cfb89a5a"); ?

Comment: just not able to figure that out, i did read those posts, and implemented that, but no difference at all

Comment: i read on a forum to add this line, removing it as well has no affect at all

Comment: i'm able to get the result without any error with your code.is internet permission is set?

Comment: i figured that out, basicaly, when declaring string, i made typo, i wrote "jason" instead of json,

Comment: Great but even i use jason or json, i still get the result without any error

Answer (score 0):

You need to append the Open Weather API key to the url.