# Unknown error while calling Web API from Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

i am trying to send a `JSONObject` as input parameter for a C# Web API with the following code

```
protected String doInBackground(JSONObject... companyInfo) {

    try {
        URL url;
        URLConnection urlConn;

        url = new URL(HOST_NAME + WEB_API_METHOD);

        urlConn = url.openConnection();
        urlConn.setDoInput(true);
        urlConn.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConn.setUseCaches(false);
        urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        urlConn.setRequestProperty("Host", HOST_NAME);
        urlConn.connect();

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(urlConn.getOutputStream());
        out.print(companyInfo[0]);
        out.close();

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
        }
        bufferedReader.close();

        Log.i("companyInfo > ", stringBuilder.toString());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.e("Exception", ex.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
```

When this is called, the method doesn't execute and when i try to catch the error, i don't get a meaningful message. it shows the URL name and thats it.

I am unable to find the issue and any help would be appreciated.

this is the error i got

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://MY_FULL_URL
     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:238)
     at com.fourtyninetons.NewCompanyActivity$saveCompanyProfile.doInBackground(NewCompanyActivity.java:103)
     at com.fourtyninetons.NewCompanyActivity$saveCompanyProfile.doInBackground(NewCompanyActivity.java:70)
     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Lakshman.

Comment: `ex.printStackTrace()` ?

Comment: update the error here

Comment: `ex.printstackTrace()` says `java.io.FileNotFoundException: FULL_URL_OF_WEB_API`

Comment: @MuchOverflow `ex.printStackTrace` worked and I got the above message.

Comment: error says: `FileNotFoundException: http://MY_FULL_URL` are you sure `HOST_NAME` and `WEB_API_METHOD` have the correct values?

Comment: the problem is resolved @Yazan. See the below answer. thanks

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the solution of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16255823/httpurlconnection-java-io-filenotfoundexception) question, the problem is with the web api method and the backend database. Fiddler helped me solve the issue and the above code is working fine.

Useful Tip: When anyone gets this `FileNotFoundException`user POSTMAN or FIDDLER to execute the method and find for the errors.

Thank you everyone who attempted to solve this.