# Cannot connect to https with HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection, httpsurlconnection

I try to make a GET/POST to `http://www.android.com/` like in the example given in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)

In the `InputStream` I get a message saying `302 Moved` and tells me to go on `https://www.android.com/`

When I modify my `URL` to https, I get:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://www.android.com/

```
HttpsURLConnection con;
String request = "https://www.android.com/";
URL url = new URL(request);
    con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    con.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postDataLength));
```

***Update***

I thought it was an issue of SSL certificates, but it is not. I've added a function that will blindly trust all SSL certificates. Sources [here](http://www.javased.com/index.php?api=javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory) and [here](http://www.javased.com/index.php?source_dir=incubator-cordova-android/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/F).

Comment: You should cast to `HttpsURLConnection` instead of `HttpURLConnection`

Comment: I tried to declare as `HttpsURLConnect` and cast too, but same issue.

Comment: See if this helps in any way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16255823/httpurlconnection-java-io-filenotfoundexception

Comment: He solved his problem by checking his URL and setting `con.setDoOutput(true);`. I've already made this

Answer (score 2):

Once I had the same problem which solved when I used `HttpsURLConnection` Instead of `HttpURLConnection`.