# Why no data is being written in the file?

Tags: java, android, url, android-file

I created an application to download image file from url, but there isin't any data in the file

**Image URL:** https://instagram.fidr1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/e35/190664842_184685183538740_5039921250568173600_n.jpg?tp=1&_nc_ht=instagram.fidr1-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=108&_nc_ohc=RrEU4lTwYCwAX-vgVQ4&edm=AABBvjUBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=3ac34be54793fa59134380fd9e0bd617&oe=60DCB7E6&_nc_sid=83d603

The code:

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {

    try {
        URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 
        (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) 
        Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2");
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.connect();

        File file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File f1 = new File(file, "_Url download");
        if(!f1.exists()){
            f1.mkdir();
        }

        fileName = System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";

        File f2 = new File(f1, fileName);
        f2.createNewFile();

        InputStream er = con.getErrorStream();
        Log.i("ErrorCode", con.getResponseCode()+"");
        Log.i("ErrorMessage", con.getResponseMessage());
        Log.i("ErrorStream", er+"");

        InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f2);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len;

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(buffer));

        while((len = in.read(buffer, 0, 1024)) > 0) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }

        out.close();
        in.close();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.i("IOException", e.toString());
    }
    return null;
}
```

**Result:**

[Image of file path where the file is being saved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htiGq.png)

**EDIT**

**Download Button:**

```
downloadButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)  != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 101);
            }
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)  != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 102);
            }
            else if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.INTERNET)  != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.INTERNET}, 103);
            }
            else {
                BackgroundTask task = new BackgroundTask(this);
                task.execute(et.getText().toString());
            }
        });
```

**Manifest Permissions:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

**EDIT2**

*Log:*

```
2021-06-26 09:26:25.532 26760-26890/com.example.urldownload I/ErrorCode: 400

2021-06-26 09:26:25.533 26760-26890/com.example.urldownload I/ErrorMessage: Bad Request

2021-06-26 09:26:25.533 26760-26890/com.example.urldownload I/Errorstream: buffer(com.android.okhttp.internal.http.Http1xStream$FixedLengthSource@fbb2c70).inputStream()

2021-06-26 09:26:25.534 26760-26890/com.example.urldownload I/IOException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://instagram.fidr1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/e35/190664842_184685183538740_5039921250568173600_n.jpg?tp=1&_nc_ht=instagram.fidr1-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=108&_nc_ohc=RrEU4lTwYCwAX-vgVQ4&edm=AABBvjUBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=3ac34be54793fa59134380fd9e0bd617&oe=60DCB7E6&_nc_sid=83d603
```

Comment: First things first, you have a space in your file-name. Probably not what you want.
System.currentTimeMillis() + "<space-here> .jpg"

Comment: Maybe you don't have rights to write to external storage? Check permissions

Comment: Using your code as is, I am able to download the image file. Can you make sure that the background task is running as expected?
Also, you are eating up all the exceptions. If there are any errors you won't know about them. Probably translate them up to the caller so that you have visibility into background threads.

Comment: @Maverick  Why does throws java.io.FileNotFound Exception for the url which is working fine.

Comment: Sorry, did not understand your comment. Is it throwing FileNotFound in the background thread?

Comment: Also, please share the output of `con.getResponseCode`. Check method 'getErrorStream' (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html).

Comment: @Maverick please have a look at **Edit2**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16255823/httpurlconnection-java-io-filenotfoundexception). It seems `setDoOutput(true)` changes request method to POST.

Comment: What was it? Please share!

Comment: I changed setDoOutput(true) to setDoOutput(false), and it worked.

Comment: Could you please mark the answer as accepted if it helped?